# flutter firebase: Change property with corresponding data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, textstyle

I have an app where a collection has a field 'Status'. This field changes with the use of streamBuilder. works well. I can access the updated changes.
However, I want to change the TextStyle of that particular field depending the the data in the fied 'Status'.
The data in the 'Status' field are : 'not verified', 'pending verification', 'verified'.
I want the textstyle(say the color) to change depending on the 'Status of the user

I have no idea how to do it. Any help.

Here is the code:

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

StreamBuilder(
                                stream: users.doc(uid).snapshots(),
                                builder: (BuildContext context,
                                    AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                  String status = snapshot.data['Status'];
                                  
                                  if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                      ConnectionState) {
                                    return const Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                    );
                                  }

                                  return Text(status);
                                }),
                          ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Map` with the statuses and the colors assigned to each of them:

```
const statusColors = <String, Color> {
  'not verified': Colors.red,
  'pending verification': Colors.orange,
  'verified': Colors.green,
};
```

In the `StreamBuilder` assign a `TextStyle` with color based on this map; you can use the `style` parameter of the `Text` widget:

```
return Text(status, style: TextStyle(color: statusColors[status]));
```